# MySQL: get distinct values from two columns and check whether they occur in two other columns of the same table

Tags: mysql, select, join, self-join

I have been twisting my brain over this for quite a while now. So it's time to ask you guys. I have the following (simpified) MySQL table called 'fam':

```
+--------------+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+
+ Year         + ParentID1  + ParentID2  + ChildID1  + ChildID2  +
+--------------+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+
+ 1970         + 1111       + 2222       + 3333      + 4444      +
+ 1975         + 1111       + 3434       + 4545      + 5656      +
+ 1980         + 2222       + 3344       + 5566      + 6677      +
+ 1990         + 5656       + 3333       + 9090      + 0909      +
+ 1995         + 4444       + 5656       + 1010      + 1313      +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

What I basically want to achieve is to check how many of the children became parents themselves later on. I thought something like this might work

```
SELECT COUNT(fam1.ChildID1)+COUNT(fam1.ChildID2) as `recruits`
FROM fam fam1
JOIN fam fam2
ON (fam1.ChildID1=fam2.ParentID1 OR fam1.ChildID1=fam2.ParentID2) 
OR (fam1.ChildID2=fam2.ParentID1 OR fam1.ChildID2=fam2.ParentID2)
```

But, alas, there aren't 8 recruits but only 3 (3333, 4444, and 5656). The biggest problem for me to get my head around is how to account for the fact that the IDs can appear in different columns (for example 5656 is in column 1 in 1990 and in column 2 in 1995).

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this

```
    select count(*) as `recruits` from
    (
     select  ChildID1 from fam
     where ChildID1 in 
     (select ParentID1 from fam 
       union 
      select ParentID2 from fam)
     union

     select ChildID2 from fam
     where ChildID2 in 
     (select ParentID1 from fam 
     union
     select ParentID2 from fam)

    )t;
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/03cc2/22)

Comment: your answer is basically the same as mine, except for the distinct argument.
You don't need it, a child can only belong to one family as a child... hence the use of distinct is pointless and only uses computer resources.

Comment: That's a solid facepalm over here. Dunno why I kept tying knots into my brain when the solution is actually that easy. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

It is quite easy, you need only to check if a child have became parent... and because each family has two child you need to do it twice (once for child one and another for child two) and you should have the list of all child whom became parents. And after you have them in the list you only need to count them, see no need to complicate what is easy ;)

```
  select count (*) from
    (
        select child1 from fam
         where child1 in 
            (select parent1 from fam 
               union 
              select parent2 from fam)

        union

        select child2 from fam
         where child2 in 
           (select parent1 from fam 
             union
            select parent2 from fam)

    );
```

Comment: Thanks heaps for your effort! Much appreciated! But isn't your solution missing the required table alias? I accepted echo_Samir's solution as it works off the shelf and he went to the trouble to create a fiddle for it.

Comment: @Tomm he copied my answer... people like him should be banned